# viewWillDisappear error/stop playing sound when i change viewController

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I have some ViewCotroller where i tapped a button - some audio file is playing. I want to stop playing audio when change/close this ViewController. How I can do this?

I try add some method to viewWillDisappear and it crashed if I don't tap any button. But if I tapped some button - it will works fine.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class BossViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //MARK: - Stop sound when we're change/close this viewController

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
```

This is how my button is look like:

```
@IBAction func boss1(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let audioFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "shamp", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFile as URL)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Problem in getting File")
        }

        audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

Comment: @a-lebedko : Whats the crash ? Edit your question and add crash log/description to help us understand the problem better

Comment: If my answer works for you, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark so that others with the same problem can be directed to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the audio player is playing, as @SandeepBhandari mentioned, or you can use a `Bool` variable to keep track whether or not the user tapped the button:

```
var buttonTapped = false

@IBAction func boss1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    ...
    buttonTapped = true
}
```

Then, you can check the variable in your `viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` method:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if buttonTapped {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```